# Empty return value from a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following...

```
/* Request access tokens from twitter */
$access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
echo $access_token[2];
```

"$access_token" is an array, Im trying to retrieve a value from this array only the above echo doesn't seem to echo anything?

**dump var**

```
array(4) { ["oauth_token"]=> string(50) "81920494-vHspkpas4WiOYoFKCgto85mW2XeTxuA130MwcHHWb" ["oauth_token_secret"]=> string(42) "WwIYybFivEwZQ1ORbeqY1irHT385EIuh27alWy9ED4" ["user_id"]=> string(8) "81989494" ["screen_name"]=> string(12) "KlareB" }
```

Comment: Can you print the results of `var_dump($access_token);`

Comment: You really seem to have a problem comprehending arrays. If the key says `["user_id"]`, then the key is `["user_id"]`. Only if the key says `[2]`, then the key is `[2]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the var_dump is:

```
array(4) { ["oauth_token"]=> string(50) "81920494-vHspkpas4WiOYoFKCgto85mW2XeTxuA130MwcHHWb" ["oauth_token_secret"]=> string(42) "WwIYybFivEwZQ1ORbeqY1irHT385EIuh27alWy9ED4" ["user_id"]=> string(8) "81920494" ["screen_name"]=> string(12) "KlareBrennan" }
```

Then `echo $access_array[2];` wont work because its not indexed numerically.

You would need to do:

```
echo $access_array['user_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise was so simple

Comment: No problem :) its not easy unless you know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to remember than in PHP arrays are actually hashmaps. That is to say that they are an associative array of `key => value` pairs.

```
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
echo $access_token[2];
```

This means the above code will look in the `$access_token` array not at *position* `2` but at *key* `2`. We can see from your vardump there is no key `2`:

```
array(4) { 
  ["oauth_token"]=> string(50) "81920494-vHspkpas4WiOYoFKCgto85mW2XeTxuA130MwcHHWb
  ["oauth_token_secret"]=> string(42) "WwIYybFivEwZQ1ORbeqY1irHT385EIuh27alWy9ED4" 
  ["user_id"]=> string(8) "81920494" 
  ["screen_name"]=> string(12) "KlareBrennan" 
}
```

Note that for most indexed arrays this functions exactly the same way, which is what leads to your confusion. Please consider the following code:

```
<?php

  $blah = array();
  $blah['mykey'] = "My first key.";
  $blah[] = "My second key.";
  $blah[1] = "My third key.";
  $blah[] = "My last key.";

  var_dump($blah);
```

And it's results:

```
array(4) {
  ["mykey"]=>
  string(13) "My first key."
  [0]=>
  string(14) "My second key."
  [1]=>
  string(13) "My third key."
  [2]=>
  string(12) "My last key."
}
```

We can see that if no key is specified the next available key is use; and in this numerals are assigned as keys for the key-value pair, but that they can live alongside string keys. For this reason [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) is a useful function if you want to iterate over *all* the contents of an array.